# Not beginning with https://

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to redirect request to other url if and only if the url is not beginning with https://

I just need the pattern. The pattern I use is:

```
^(.*)$
```

But this redirects user even if the url is beginning with https://

What condition should add in above pattern?

Comment: It says anything can occur in url. Didn't you know that?

Comment: @user606723: Did I ask help from you? Why don't you just leave this post quietly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure just make it ^(https.*)$

Comment: currently your regex matches everything with a beginning and an end and 0 to infinte letters in the middle.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Works perfectly. But how does it work? Doesn't ^(https.*)$ mean match any url beginning with https? because ^ stands for beginning with.

Comment: yeah it matches anything that begins with https. You'd have to post the rest of the code it's used in to explain it fully but you have it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the pattern you want to use:

```
^(?!https://)
```

This means "at the beginning of the string, check that the next characters to come up are *not* `https://`". Be sure that your regex system supports this feature called lookaheads, though!

Comment: Thanks Nayuki. Even Josh's pattern works. But I didn't understand how that works.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this question is extremely elementary.

Please read the following.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html

Specifically,
http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html